# Changing the prompt in a multilanguage knitr/RMarkdown document

Tags: r, bash, knitr, r-markdown

I'm writing a `.Rmd` file that displays both bash commands and R commands. Is there a way to differentiate the chunks with R code from those with bash code? There's a knitr chunk option that inserts the R command prompt into a chunk so that

````
```{R, prompt = "true"}
plot(rnorm(100))
```
````

becomes

```
> plot(rnorm(100))
```

but for the bash chunks this

````
```{bash, prompt = "true"}
pandoc --version
```
````

becomes this

```
> pandoc --version
```

when I would prefer this

```
$ pandoc --version
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try a simple hook:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library('knitr')
knit_hooks$set(
  prompt = function(before, options, envir) {
    options(prompt = if (options$engine %in% c('sh','bash')) '$ ' else 'R> ')
})
```

```{r, prompt=TRUE}
1+1
```

but for the bash chunks this

```{bash, prompt=TRUE}
pandoc --version | head -1
```

```{r, prompt=TRUE}
1+1
```
````

[image]

And you can add `opts_chunk$set(prompt=TRUE)` so you don't have to keep writing `prompt=TRUE` for every chunk

Comment: This is a really nice example of how to use knitr hooks. I hadn't groked them until now.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little clunky but I just realized I can "toggle" the prompt doing this:

````
```{r, echo = F}
options(prompt = "$ ")
```

```{bash, eval = F, prompt = T}
pandoc --version
```

```{r, echo = F}
options(prompt = "> ")
```

```{r, eval = F, prompt = T}
plot(rnorm(100))
```
````

which gives

```
$ pandoc --version
> plot(rnorm(100))
```